# Why is $M-; syntactically valid and what does it do?

Tags: php

I don't consider myself as PHP expert but I've designed several pages now containing a couple of thousand lines of code each. For my current project which is for a game site I drew back on an existing function which contains the line

```
$M–;
```

Now my basic understanding of PHP tells me this doesn't work since it should be -- for short -1. But it's not a dash, the script runs without error (`error_reporting (E_ALL)`) but echoing `$M` before and after gives me the same value.

So what does it do and why don't I get an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an en dash, which to PHP is just a random byte without specific meaning. `$M–`, or in UTF-8 encoding `4DE28093`, is a valid variable name. Just like `$漢字`.

<strike>A single variable by itself just initializes that variable to `null` if it doesn't already exist,</strike> the line doesn't do anything <strike>else.</strike>

Comment: Well guess i've never heared of an en dash and thought it'd just be a single dash... explains everything. The function works without as it's the delimiter for max runs which is set to 50000 which won't ever be reached anyways... guess i'll correct it to $M--; and report the original coder about his mistake... thanks a lot!

Comment: In my PHP/5.4.5 box, it doesn't initialize the variable.

Comment: @user Maybe someone was typing in Word and `--` got autocorrected...? :-3

Comment: @Álvaro Oh, you're right. That line literally doesn't do anything. Wow, PHP never ceases to amaze.

Comment: Just came to my mind: Maybe someone pasted that function into word once and it converted the double dash to an en dash? Because I don't see the point where one should grab the charmap to add an en dash to a variable that is supposed to decrease by one every time a loop runs... ??

Comment: And that's why you never let Word near code. In fact, why you never let anything near Word. ;)

Answer (score 2):

That code of your *will* result in a notice. First because that isn't a minus sign `–` vs `-` <- different (unless you have a variable name defined `M–`).

> [Notice: Undefined variable: M– in](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2xkRZQ)

Second even if it was a minus sign it would spit out a notice.

> [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wZMqB2)

If anything it only shows you haven't properly enabled full error reporting or that you are using unicode characters in variable names just to screw with other people reading your code (including yourself). ;)

**UPDATE**

I misread your code a bit. What happens is that you have are initializing the variable `M–` when doing that line so `M–` will be `null`.

Comment: Ohhh, so it's valid because it's a Unicode character and not the standard ASCII hyphen? How cool. Think of the possibilities to confuse future generations!

Comment: @PeeHaa - Not in my Windows PHP/5.4.5 version :-?

Comment: Hmmmmm. Don't you guys see the link under my second notice in my post? How can that throw a notice?

Comment: If you try to `echo` a nonexistent variable or otherwise *use* it, you'll get a notice. The literal code in the OP just initializes the variable.

Comment: Well as i said i got passed that function and as you can tell by my question i was puzzled enough to register here for finding my error. turns out it's not an true error.

Comment: @PeeHaa - Your codepad is not the original code. It contains an echo.

Comment: I noticed and have updated my answer. It's not even 12 o clock c'mon ;)

Comment: I've been sitting at this problem since 8am :P

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it might be interpreting it as `$M - null;` $M minus zero essentially. Which wouldn't do anything?

Comment: That said I just stuck an equivalent into a file (didn't have access before) and it gives me expected `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'`